How to set specific headers for a file using caddy
I'm trying to host game build files using caddy. I need those files to have specific headers, otherwise the frontend won't know how to handle them and the game won't play.
Here's my Caddyfile
racing.<my domain> {
        root * /home/<my home directory>/caddy

        # Serve .data.gz and .symbols.json.gz with the correct headers
        handle_path /Build/Build.data.gz {
                header Content-Encoding gzip
                header Content-Type application/gzip
                precompressed gzip
                file_server
        }

        # Serve .js.gz with the correct headers
        handle_path /Build/Build.framework.js.gz {
                header Content-Encoding gzip
                header Content-Type application/javascript
                precompressed gzip
                file_server
        }

        # Serve .wasm.gz with the correct headers
        handle_path /Build/Build.wasm.gz {
                header Content-Encoding gzip
                header Content-Type application/wasm
                precompressed gzip
                file_server
        }

        # Serve .js with the correct headers
        handle_path /Build/Build.loader.js {
                header Content-Type text/javascript
                precompressed gzip
                file_server
        }

        # Default handling for other files, e.g., frontend routes
        try_files {path} /index.html
        file_server
}

As you can see, I have tried to set specific headers for each file, but they have "text/html" content-type when they get on my browser.
I am new to Caddyfiles, and I feel like it is a syntax issue/misuse of certain tags.

Instead of using handle_path, I need to use header as defined in Caddy's documentation here https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/directives/header
Here's the corrected version of my Caddyfile
<my domain> {
        root * /home/<my username>/caddy

        header /Build/Build.data.gz {
            Content-Encoding gzip
            Content-Type application/gzip
        }
        header /Build/Build.framework.js.gz {
            Content-Encoding gzip
            Content-Type application/javascript
        }
        header /Build/Build.wasm.gz {
            Content-Encoding gzip
            Content-Type application/wasm
        }
        header /Build/Build.loader.js {
            Content-Type text/javascript
        }

        # Default handling for other files, e.g., frontend routes
        try_files {path} /index.html
        file_server
}

